# Drywall stain bleeding thru after 5 coats of paint

Tags: drywall, leak, paint, stain

My drywall was wet before due to a leak. It has a stain mark. But after 5 coats of white paint from Behr brand and Kilz primer, the yellow stain is still bleeding thru

[image]

In the past, I remember I had to scrape off the paper and put new mud/sand again. Then prime, paint.

Now it is all done already with texture and paint. Is there a better way to fix this?

I am thinking about getting the white color from Sherwin Williams but I am not sure if it does any difference.

Comment: are you confident the spot is dry and no longer impacted? One of those issues where you are sure it is resolved, but it isn't? Just worth mentioning.

Comment: @noybman Yes the roof leak has been fixed and other side of drywall open to monitor for 2 weeks. So unless the old moisture is still there...

Comment: I would presume a heavier quality primer & paint could work but its definitely not certain. Killz has worked for me, and not worked for me. I've had inconsistent results the few times I had to cover a stain.

Comment: @noybman I had this happened 2 times before. One was not a leak but some stain in kitchen ceiling probably due to old drywall. That was so stubborn that I had to rip the paper and re-mudded it.

Comment: There is a barrier paint available, but I have also used a white craft type glue which dries clear with success.

Comment: @SolarMike Can you recommend brand of paint or place to buy?

Comment: You have to look, what is available in your location is not the same as mine... are you making this a shopping question...

Comment: Don't think about paint as brands - think about what is in it.  Any brand of water based primer will give you issues. Killz has a very powerful brand name, but they have several types of primer and some of the ones they sell the most of aren't great for challenging stains.

Comment: epoxy paint, like for garage floors, should block it.

Comment: Get a good "stain blocker".  It's not the same as a primer.

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately there are not many things that are soluble in both oil and water.

If it's a water stain use an oil based undercoat, or a shellac based sealer.

If it's an oil, grease, or wax, stain use a water based undercoat.

Use two coats of undercoat to get a good seal.

Comment: Shellac base gets my vote, after my grandfather passed we tried painting his room (heavy smoker) to make a long story short after using a shellac based primer sealer the tar quit bleeding through. Zinsser has a really good one but it is ~45$ per gallon.

Comment: +1 for Shellac. Absolutely you need the Zinsser shellac,  I would then give it two coats of a good BONDING primer, then paint.

Comment: Indeed that was the stuff I was thinking of.